# Nohup does not run process in background

Tags: linux, ssh, nohup

I run

```
nohup bash -c "while [ true ]; do echo test; done"
```

from `PuTTy` SSH client, but after this process is not running in background instead `nohup` keeps to be foreground process in shell.

SW version: `nohup (GNU coreutils) 8.5`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
nohup bash -c "while [ true ]; do echo test; done" &
```

Nohup provides you immunity to hangup signals. But it does not automatically set the process to background.

It's the & at the end of the command that causes it to run in the background.